# SQL Server excel "data mining" addin error message

Tags: sql-server, excel-addins, sql-server-2016

I have a problem about using SQLServer "data mining" addin on excel.
Below programs installed on my PC:

- SQLServer 2016 CTP2.0 64bit
- Office 2013 pro plus 64bit
- SQLServer 2012 data mining addin 64bit

I activated the data mining addin and connected to an analysis service database using the connection wizard. However I can not see the name of tab related to data mining tools in the ribbon; also the one under table tools is invisible. Actually they are there but they have no label. Only there are small blank tab area which I can click an see all the related data mining tools.

When I try to use any of these tools it gives the error message:

> "object reference not set to an instance of an object".

What can be the problem?

- Two years ago I installed and used these dm tools on my previous PC with SQLServer 2012 but now I can't do it with the version 2016. Is SQLServer 2012 data mining addin only compatible with SQL server 2012? I tried to find an updated version of the addin but couldn't find.
- Do I need to install visual studio and create a new analysis service connection using it? I won't use visual studio for any other purpose so I don't want to install it if its not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve the error:

> Object not set to instance of object

Even Microsoft has no clue how to fix data mining excel plugin issue, when we click on query button it throws  Object reference not set to instance of object exception.

If you need further clarification, let me know.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you earn sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post. If you have a related but different question, ask a new question referencing this one if it will help provide context.